# Is this a termite?

Tags: pest-control, pest, insect, termite

There's a bunch of these critters on my window sill. There doesn't appear to be damage from what I can tell, but I don't know if it's termites. They are super tiny so I had to zoom in with my phone all the way.

I also created a video https://youtu.be/yXhLeEN38Ks as the photo here is hard to see because of the zoom.

[image]

Comment: Approximately where in the world are you? picture doesn't look like termite. Antennae tool long, and has wings?

Comment: Virginia, USA. Did you see the video ? It's better quality

Comment: Unlike  any termites I see in E TX ( subterranean ) .Our termites are pale in color and have two body segments rather than the traditional insect with three .

Comment: it looks and moves like a bee ... probably a mason bee ... they find a hole in wood, brick, or anything really ... then they lay an egg inside, add some food and cover it with a mud plug ... these are very beneficial to have around

Comment: Can't be a bee- it has no wings. Also it's super tiny, much smaller than a bee. The width of a pencil lead